# custom fields in paypal for php

Tags: php, paypal, custom-fields

I am using paypal Express checkout api. i need to pass my userid to the paypal as a custom field though the api in setexpresscheckout.php. i surfed net and researched and found that the custom value can be send like this:

```
<input type=hidden value="Something" name="custom"/>
```

but the problem is that we should do it directly posting the form to the paypal site like this

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
.....
</form>
```

but due to api i am posting my form like this:

```
<form id="paypalfrm" name="paypalfrm" action="pay_pal/SetExpressCheckout.php" method="post">
....
</form>
```

so the above custom method doesnot work.So please can anybody help me here??? How should i pass my userid to the paypal site...??

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to pass your userId to PayPal ?
If you just need to be able to retrieve your userID when you process the payment with DoExpressCheckoutPayment, you could use PHP session to store your userID in your SetExpessCheckout.php script.

Comment: im using an ipn listner and i need to store the orders through ipn lisnter to its dedicated user id.and in listner we cannot use the session...

Comment: Maybe when you receive PDT answer from DoExpressCheckout, you can store your userID in your database, associated with a PayPal ID like the transactionID ? So when you listen IPN, you get a transactionID and retrieve your userID.

Comment: i am not using PDT.and if i store the user id in database, in a case when there are multiple user id in the table then how can i distinguish the users????

Comment: I use NVP API, when I call DoExpressCheckout I get an answer. Here I check the "ACK" parameter of this answer to know if the API call is ok. In this answer I also have a "PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID" parameter, so I can store this transactionID with my userID in database. One transactionID is associated with one userID